# How can I enforce that an attribute equals one of the constant values (in Java)?

Tags: java, enums

I have a class `Game` with an attriburte "status" and this attribute will be just "player" or "coach", how could i do that?i will give you how i tried

```
class Status{
   public static final String player = "player";
   public static final String coach = "coach";
}
class Game {
   String status;
   Game(String status){
     this.status = status;
   }
}
class Main{
   public static void main(String args[]){
     new Game(Status.player);
     new Game(Status.coach);
   }
}
```

thank you

Comment: You can enforce this at runtime by throwing `IllegalArgumentException` when an invalid argument is passed in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use an enumeration

```
public class Game {
   public enum Status { PLAYER, COACH };
   private Status status;
   public Game(Status status){
     this.Status = status;
   }

public static void main(String args[]){
     new Game(Status.PLAYER);
     new Game(Status.COACH);
   }
}
```

Comment: You cant say `new Game(PLAYER)`. Say `new Game(Status.PLAYER)` instead.

Comment: Shouldn't be `public static enum Status { PLAYER, COACH };` ? (I added `static`)

Comment: @GaborSch Yes for it to be accessed by static main, it has to be static enum. Good call.